# Is there any way to get the unique device id from android

Tags: android

i want unique device id from android device. I want unique device id from android device how to get that one.

Comment: Refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Answer (score 1):

yes you can get android device mac id which is known as unique identifier assigned to network interfaces for communications on the physical network segment this is a unique id for each device which cannot be changed however.

you can get it by WIFImanager in android

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String MACAddress = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
```

dont forget to add permission to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"> </uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any (perfect) way to do this. See [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html). If you just want to identify the user, you can generate one UUID and store it in your application's storage.

Answer (score 1):

have created once class and use this in my app see [pastie](http://pastie.org/private/zgv5ys0osmlidb3wfxia)

its create unique ID and generate MD5 message as string of unique device ID

```
public String getUDID(Context c) {

    // Get some of the hardware information
    String buildParams = Build.BOARD + Build.BRAND + Build.CPU_ABI
            + Build.DEVICE + Build.DISPLAY + Build.FINGERPRINT + Build.HOST
            + Build.ID + Build.MANUFACTURER + Build.MODEL + Build.PRODUCT
            + Build.TAGS + Build.TYPE + Build.USER;

    // Requires READ_PHONE_STATE
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) c
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    // gets the imei (GSM) or MEID/ESN (CDMA)
       String imei = tm.getDeviceId();

      //gets the android-assigned id you can omit this because 
      //It's known to be null sometimes, it's documented as "can change upon factory reset". 
      //Use at your own risk, and it can be easily changed on a rooted phone.
    String androidId = Secure.getString(c.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    // requires ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    // gets the MAC address
    String mac = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();

    // concatenate the string
    String fullHash = buildParams + imei + androidId + mac;

    return md5(fullHash);

}
```

**md5(String fullHash)** Function

```
public String md5(String toConvert) {

    String retVal = "";

    MessageDigest algorithm;
    try {
        algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(toConvert.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
        }
        retVal = hexString + "";
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple, actually..

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Using Secure.ANDROID_ID is not recommanded in most cases.

Comment: What you think could go wrong, if you use it in this case?

Comment: The ANDROID_ID can change after a factory reset, so basically it depend of what you really want.